# Azure Web App Service / Rest API - How to upload a website page

Tags: azure, rest, azure-web-app-service

I have a web app service on azure that is hosting a RESTful api which deals with my MySQL database. I am wondering if its possible to somehow (either manually, or otherwise) upload a page to this app service as well. For instance, i have my URL from azure, and my API lives under /api

I was wondering if i can create a php/html page or something that I can upload to /meetingConfirm

so i can do something like /meetingConfirm?id=hash

And have a page which i can send email links to encoded for each meeting, to allow people to respond to invites. It would be a simple page that just updates a value via the API and then displays a confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you **don't** need a separate page to be uploaded for each user. You can just add a `multi-threading Id generator` code and save the last used `Id` in your DB for future requests.

I am referring to a solution like this(as I am not sure about your tech stack, sharing python approach): [How do you generate random unique identifiers in a multi process and multi thread environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687344/how-do-you-generate-random-unique-identifiers-in-a-multi-process-and-multi-threa)

Comment: I'm aware of generating an id and using it as a url parameter - that's not the question. The question is I have an API that is blocked by authentication and the people on question won't actually have accounts, how can they access it temporarily in the first place

Comment: Then, you can add a dummy page(in your solution and not dynamically) to show confirmation/any other message and as soon as the user hits that page, the Id in query parameter is read by your API and the API is triggered. Does that answer your question?